# Why does this code fail with Ecto.NoPrimaryKeyValueError

Tags: elixir, ecto

Why does this fail:

```
%Partner{} |> cast(%{id: 123}, [:id]) |> delete
```

with a `Ecto.NoPrimaryKeyValueError`? I'm setting the primary key explicitly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For changesets, the `id` from the original struct (`data`) is used by `Repo.delete`, and not the one in `changes`, and `cast` puts the new `id` only in `changes`. You can either merge `changes` into the original struct (`data`):

```
%Partner{} |> cast(%{id: 123}, [:id]) |> Ecto.Changeset.apply_changes |> delete
```

or put the `id` into `%Partner{}` manually:

```
%Partner{id: 123} |> delete
```

Comment: Nice answer, new-ish to elixir and fixed my issue. This answer explains to me what a Changeset actually is quite well.